# JPush works all over the world?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an android application that can receive push notifications. This app will be localised in multiple languages and should work in China as well. I know all google services are blocked in China. So, I cannot use GCM. I found some alternatives like [JPush](http://documentation.kii.com/en/samples/push-notifications/push-notifications-jpush/). Now the only doubt I have is, does jPush work only in China? Or it works across the globe? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mailed the customer support of jPush. They mentioned it works worldwide. Below is their response.

> We've confirmed that JPush works outside China.
>   However, maybe due to network stability issue, we experienced some delay of message delivery.
>   So we recommend you to check if the stability of JPush is enough for your app.